# Sorting student that are regular and irregular student

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I Want to select the student that dont have a failing grade in its row.

```
 Stud_id   grade_1    grade_2    grade_3    RATE
  123        1.5       3.00        2.00    regular
  234        2.00      1.50        5.00    irregular   
  567        3.00      2.00        2.00    regular
```

select COUNT(stud_id) WHERE grade BETWEEN 1 AND 3 AND dont have grade IN(0,5).

my code for getting all the regular student is this.

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT stud_id FROM grade
 WHERE grade BETWEEN 1 AND 3 AND stud_id ='$student')
```

But my problem here is the student that have failed grade will also count since he also pass the other grade.

[Sample mysql picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw94e.png)

as you can see in the picture the student with ID ='67453432' should only be the student that will appear with "REGULAR" status because he doesnt have any failed grade. while the other student will appear as "IRREGULAR" since they have 1 or more failing grade.

the result should be like this

```
 EXAMPLE ONLY!!!
    if grade BETWEEN 1 AND 3 AND Dont have 0.00 OR 5.00 = REGULAR
     BUT if GRADE BETWEEN 1 AND 3 AND HAVE 0.0 OR 5.00 = IRREGULAR

    Stud_ID   RATE
    67453432 REGULAR
     123     REGULAR
     234     IRREGULAR
     567     REGULAR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the irregular students by the below query:

```
SELECT stud_id, 'Irregular'
FROM students
WHERE grade IN (0,5);
```

And regular students by the below query:

```
SELECT stud_id, 'Regular'
FROM students
WHERE grade BETWEEN 1 AND 3
AND stud_id NOT IN (
    SELECT stud_id
    FROM students
    WHERE grade IN (0,5)
);
```

Now, you can `UNION` these two queries to get the result, e.g.:

```
SELECT stud_id, 'Irregular'
FROM students
WHERE grade IN (0,5)

UNION

SELECT stud_id, 'Regular'
FROM students
WHERE grade BETWEEN 1 AND 3
AND stud_id NOT IN (
    SELECT stud_id
    FROM students
    WHERE grade IN (0,5)
);
```

Comment: OH MY GOD! OH MY GOD! IVE BEEN SEARCHING AND MAKING QUERY FOR THIS! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! HOW CAN I GIVE A MILLION LIKES FOR THIS?

Comment: yes! it works! thank you a million times! :) very helpful!

Comment: @MikeAhrenRances can you mark the answer as accepted in that case? [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) how to do it.